# Confusing about forward and reverse proxy

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx, proxy

I am wp begginner, on my wordpress site there are some embedded videos(youtube , vimeo etc). But in some countries youtube is blocked by ISP(or administrator) so visitors cannot see videos.

In this case should i implement forward or reverse proxy on server to allow visitors to watch embedded videos?
Apart from proxy solutiton is there an easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by implementing forward proxy. Installed apache server(xampp) on vps. It is working as forward proxy. All requests by the client is consuming by the proxy server and back to the client. You need to enable proxy modules in **httpd.conf** file before running proxy.
nginx is doing the same thing with simplier configuration but doesn't support https.

**C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

 ServerName dropbox.local
 DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/php/www"
<Directory "C:/xampp/php/www">
       Require all granted    
    </Directory>

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
#RequestHeader set Front-End-Https "On"
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  SSLProxyEngine On

# Enable forward proxy requests. It is dangerous. You need to secure the server.
ProxyRequests On

# Allows reverse proxying to https locations.
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyVerify none 
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off



# Allow requests from selected hosts or domains
<Proxy *>
 ProxyAddHeaders off
 ProxyPreserveHost off
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

ProxyVia On
AllowCONNECT 8080

# This is the main proxy configuration
ProxyPass / https://www.google.com.tr/
ProxyPassReverse / https://www.google.com.tr/

</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```